# getting "selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedExceptionSelenium" error using InstaPy

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, instagram, instapy

[SETUP:
Windows 10 x64
PyCharm 2019.3.3 (Community Edition)]

I'm trying to create a simple Insta bot with InstaPy but I keep running into the same error

CODE:

```
from instapy import InstaPy

InstaPy(username='username', password='password').login()
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Niku/PycharmProjects/InstaBot/InstaBot.py", line 6, in <module>
    InstaPy(username='Rubixmusicprod', password='Niku2020').login()
  File "C:\Users\Niku\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\instapy\instapy.py", line 309, in __init__
    self.browser, err_msg = set_selenium_local_session(
  File "C:\Users\Niku\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\instapy\browser.py", line 111, in set_selenium_local_session
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(
  File "C:\Users\Niku\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 170, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(
  File "C:\Users\Niku\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Users\Niku\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "C:\Users\Niku\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Niku\PycharmProjects\InstaBot\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Unable to find a matching set of capabilities
```

I've tried upgrading selenium, along with Geckodriver and related drivers.
It was a mission just to get InstaPy installed!
I may just have to go the browser automation way instead here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use Selenium with Geckodrive in Firefox

```
session = InstaPy(username=INSTAGRAM_LOGIN,
                  password=INSTAGRAM_PASSWORD,
                  geckodriver_path='geckodriver.exe')
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out that the InstaPy API isn't currently compatible with python 3.8, have to go back to previous version for functionality.